# jhipster prod profile : initial app shows instead of mine

Tags: tomcat7, jhipster

I have deployed my app on Tomcat.
If I set in JAVA_OPTS the prod profile, I am getting the application initially generated by Jhipster in my browser (default home page, etc.).

If I don't set the prod profile, I am getting my application in the browser with my custom home page.
I don't understand why...?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Did you clear you browser cache?

Comment: Yes. In tomcat, I have searched for "Welcome, Java Hipster" and it appeared in the file : tomcat7/webapps/myapp/dist/scripts/f98b31cc.app.js

Comment: If I change the text to "tata", "tata" appears in my browser, so it seems to be the file that is used with profile:prod. If I restart Tomcat with Dev profile, this file is still here but the home page is my custom home page, as if this file was not used with Dev profile.